# Meteor 0.9.1.1: How do I notify the client of progress when uploading a file?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm working on a simple file uploader.  I've got this working using this [test code](https://github.com/Sanjo/collectionFS_test)

When I choose a file and click the "upload" button the file is uploaded correctly, however there is no notification on the client side to let the user know what's happening.

My question is, how can I let the client know the progress of the upload?

Something like:

"uploading"

"file upload complete" /  "file upload failed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check FS.UploadProgressBar of [Meteor-cfs-ui](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-ui)